# Open application directly when NSLocalNotification is recieved

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

As the question states, is it possible to open an application, without any interaction from the user, whenever a local notification or its repeat is received or is being fired by the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. there is no way to do this since iOS don't allow that.

Comment: Yes ! It is not possible to open ios application with out user interaction , In notifications also user click the notification popup button then only application is open..!